# What are the various ways to build a responsive website?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

Responsive web design is catching up very fast. I know that twitter Bootstrap is one the best frame works available out there. But I am just wondering what are the other options. I have seen a couple of responsive website, and I am not sure if they are built using twitter boot strap. The websites I am talking about are [smashing magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/) and [css tricks](http://css-tricks.com/). Does anybody know how they are responsive, do they use twitter bootstrap or any other framework?

Answer (score 2):

Actually **Responsive Web Design** includes three ingridients: **Fluid Grid**, **Flexible Images** and **Media Queries**. If you interested in learning how to build web using RWD technique I recommend you to read **Ethan Marcotte**'s [Responsive Web Design](http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design) book.

Answer (score 1):

They both use their own custom CSS code. For a site with such a large amount of custom design, it doesn't make much sense to base in on Bootstrap.

Having said that, Bootstrap is a great framework if you don't mind building on top of quite defined code.

For responsive design, @media query is the only thing that you need. Bootstrap is just a very defined framework that is also using @media queries.

Comment: do you mean that larger websites can't be build upon bootstrap

Comment: They of course can. The issue is that bootstrap provides a specific look and feel to its elements. Depending on your needs you might now want them and in that case it makes sense to you use a 12-col (or whaterver the numbers) grid and create your own design elements.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a late answer, but there are quite a number of responsive front-end frameworks out there now: 
[Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) or [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) for example (I'm a fan of both).

The advantage of them being a very high level of customisation, fluid grid components, media queries and many other features/functions. Flexibility speaks volumes.

Of course, these are just starting points, you can customise them as little or as much as you want. The community is continually generating new ideas, [bootstrapcdn.com](http://bootstrapcdn.com) for example, providing fast-loading bootstrap files for use...

One of the most important elements to consider is how many screens your responsive site can support? 3? 4? 5? (PC, tablet, smartphone, TV etc) and how your site degrades to support different screen-sizes.